# Why is it good practice to specify the file path separately, before the read_file call?

Tags: r

I am wondering why it is good practice to specify the file path to the file that you want to load in R, and only then do the read call. I am talking about situations where you use projects in Rstudio. In these cases, the work directory is already automatically set to the project directory.
So I see people doing this:

```
file_path <- file.path("my","file","is","here","myfile.csv")
my_file <- read.csv(file_path)
```

Or:

```
library(here)
file_path <- here::here("my","file","is","here","myfile.csv")
my_file <- read.csv(file_path)
```

Instead of the simple:

```
my_file <- read.csv("my/file/is/here/myfile.csv")
```

Why is it better to first make the element file_path? It seems I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: In a word, portability. Whilst you could do `read.csv('my/file/is/here/myfile.csv')`, `file.path` automatically detects the system on which the code runs and ensures that the file path separator is appropriate to the system, since some systems may use (for example) ```\\``` as a separator rather than `/`.

Comment: I'm going to close this question as a duplicate, even though it's maybe not an exact duplicate, because the answer is essentially 'portability', and the portability of just using paths with `/` is addressed in the linked duplicate. In particular, there is an answer that links to a list of systems with different file separators on which your code might fail to run. If you think this doesn't answer your question, please ping me here in the comments and I can reopen if you think you need more information.

Comment: Well you are obvious more experienced so maybe you are better able to judge this. But the question you mention is not the same. People that look for an answer to my question will not end up on that page since it does not use the search cues a person with my question would. The question you mention is rather a follow-up question to mine. So I would think that keeping this question open is a good idea.

Comment: Oh, I don't think your question should be deleted. It's a good question, and you are quite right that people should have this page to land on if they have the same question as you. I actually tried to write an answer but found that it was just too similar to the Q&A on the linked page. I agree that it's not an exact duplicate, but I think people landing on this page will find the answer here. If you think there are some things that the linked Q&A doesn't answer, please [edit] your question to point out what they are. I will be happy to reopen and even write an answer.

Comment: FOR THE RECORD, you can ***always*** use `/` for a path delimiter. On windows, both `"C:/Users/r2/R"` and `"C:\\Users\\r2\\R"` work and point to the same directory. On linux (confirmed) and macos (not confirmed), only the former works, the latter will fail. I typically use `file.path` and, when I want to use it and not make my eyes bleed from backslash-purgatory, I use `file.path(.., fsep="/")`, and it works everywhere.

Comment: Having said that ... if you ever pass a path from R into `system` or `system2` or anything that interacts with the scary world-of-windows, forward slashes are likely to cause an error in those tools. So "portability" still reigns, but mostly when you're interacting outside of R; the rest of the time, it's an unnecessary notion of portability that makes my eyes hurt :-P